# Designing a GUI application: one VS multiple screens

Tags: wpf, user-interface

we are creating an application with the following GUI outline:
[image]

The "stuff to show for step *i*" changes dramatically.
Would it be better to design *i* separate screens, each with its own controls, or put it all on a single screen and toggle the visibility of the components?

I am looking for maintainability (I will probably need to hand the screen to a designer to improve my (bad) graphic designer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion it is better to have separate screen if only for maintainability. Separate screens will allow each step to evolve independently form the other with minimal dependencies as well as different people to work concurrently  on the design and development of the different screens

Comment: thanks Arnon. This makes sense. I was concerned about the need to duplicate some of the screen ("duplication is evil"), but I guess this is the right approach.

Comment: try to put the common logic in reusable components (object/UI components)

Answer (score 3):

I would vote for using a ContentControl for the "stuff to show for step i" with separate UserControls for each of the different steps. You can simply assign the ContentControl to whatever UserControl is selected for each step. This works particularly well if you are using the MVVM design pattern (highly encouraged).